# sql regexp_like check key value pair

Tags: sql, regex, sql-like

I would like to check in a given string which is composed with key value pair 
like `val1=value1;val2=value2;val3=val4=value4...` etc.

Now I would like to check which key has no value for instance key `val3`. Is this achievable via the use of a regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that with this regex

```
(?<=;|^)\w+(?==;|=$)
```

Note:

Lookarounds are not widely supported so this might not work!If this is so you can use this regex `(;|^)\w+=(;|$)`

Comment: `REGEXP_LIKE` does [not support lookarounds](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/ap_posix.htm#g693775).

Comment: SQL in the tags, `REGEXP_LIKE` in the title. `REGEXP_LIKE` is an Oracle operator afais.

Comment: select case when regexp_like('val1=value1;val2=value2;val3=val4=value4', '(?<=;|^)\w+(?==;|=$)') then 'ok' else 'nok' end as sa from dual; select case when regexp_like('val1=value1;val2=value2;val3=val4=value4', '(;|^)\w+=(;|$)') then 'ok' else 'nok' end as sa from dual;

Comment: Sorry it's working for a single key but not for multiple key pair value